# Android : Fatal Exception Main toast

Tags: android, runtime, java.lang.class

Hi i always have this error: Android : Fatal Exception Main!! It's my first app and so i have several problems..i can't understand how android works :( :

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.toast.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked",                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
    });
}
}
```

This is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/show_toast"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.toast"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the logcat output:

[image]

Comment: and in the log there is even this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Comment: Read the whole stacktrace not the last line only.

Comment: this is the entire log : http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/7223/schermatadel20130407172.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think You had copied the Code Form [Mykong](http://www.mkyong.com/)

It's shown that you `MainActivity.java` is  in package  `com.mkyong.android`

But in your manifest file your main package name is `com.example.toast` .You haven't mention any about files in `com.mkyong.android` in your `manifest` file

**Are you sure you are using tow package names ??** if so

So there are two options

**OPTION 1**

---

In your log it clearly says `com.example.toast.MainActivity` is not found

You  must change the package of `MainActivity.java` to `com.example.toast`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.toast.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will remove the `RuntimeException`

**OPTION 2**

---

The second option is to change in `manifest` file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.mkyong.android.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Note** That if you application contains more than one package names you must specify the package name  along with along with activity names in manifest file

eg : `android:name="com.mkyong.android.MainActivity"` where `com.mkyong.android` is package name and `MainActivity` is file name

I Prefer you to choose **OPTION 1**

To display you toast you can use

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here `MainActivity.this` is the parameter for context

You can also use this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you are beginner This [Android Boot Camp Series Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE08A97D36D5A255F) might help you

Comment: Oh God You are my hero ahah!Thx!! Only other quest.. I have to run a shell that i've created when the button is press.. how can i do it?

Comment: ok, thx now i post another quest :) your solution is been perfect.thanks. and yes, the code is copied from Mykong:).

Comment: anyway my shell is a script to free memory. this script goes in background and every 30min free memory ram. the problem is that i have to launch it with the terminal emulator..i wish that with a button in my app launch the script and with another stop it but i don't know how to do :(

Answer (score 0):

Change Application context to your context and try

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Where is the context?sorry i'm very noob i know

Comment: Copy the code i posted above and paste it instead of your toast statement

Comment: Doesn't work :'( if you want here there is the entire log : http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/7223/schermatadel20130407172.png

Comment: The app when i run the project stops and crash before enter :(

Comment: import com.example.toast.R; remove this whats that import?